# Customer support data sets for e-mail sentiment analysis

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I am looking for an annotated data set in the customer support domain for a sentiment analysis, to train my Naive Bayes Classifier. Are there any such data sets available on the internet? I am unable to find any so far.

How do I go about this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this being a 6-month old question, this response is probably only helpful to people who stumble upon this question.  You may want to consider using the data sets from the following page:

http://www.cs.uic.edu/~liub/FBS/sentiment-analysis.html

The polarity 2.0 data set from the following page is also frequently used:

http://www.cs.cornell.edu/people/pabo/movie-review-data/